# How to get text from enum via JavaScript in MVC view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, enums

Created enum class and from that enum list binded the dropdownlist in MVC view.

Now, whenever I will select the enum list from the dropdownlist at that time I want the text from the JavaScript and store in variable.

But, when I do that by **document.getelementbyid** or **name** then it shows **undefined** or **value null**

So, can you answer it that how can I get the enum name by JavaScript and store in variable

Here is my code,

Enum Class

```
namespace Nop.Core.Domain.FreeLancer
{
    public enum DocumentList
    {
        ElectricityBill = 0,
        RentAgreement = 1,
        Logo = 2,
        PanCard = 3,
        AadharCard = 4,
        BankCancelCheque = 5,
        OldItReturnFile = 6,
        InterestCertyOfFD = 7,
        AgricultureBill = 8,
        ShortTermCapitalGainProfitLossAmount = 9
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
public virtual IActionResult Edit()
{   
    var model = customer.ToModel();

    // AddDocumentListViaEnum
    var documentList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DocumentList)).Cast<DocumentList>();
    foreach (var document in documentList)
        model.AddCustomerDocumentModel.AvailableDocuments.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = document.ToString(), Value = ((int)document).ToString() });

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is the view for bind the enum item in dropdownlist

```
<select id="availabledocument" name="availabledocument"
    class="form-control"
    asp-items="@Model.AddCustomerDocumentModel.AvailableDocuments" onchange="OtherDocument(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Now, upto this everything is alright. Now I want to fetch the name from JavaScript and store in variable.

Here is that view code,

```
function OtherDocument(documentValue) {
    var storeValue = document.getElementById("availabledocument").value;
    var storeValue1 = document.getElementByName("availabledocument").value;
}
```

This both line of code is not working.

Comment: The first line should work, however the current value should already be passed into the function as `documentValue`. No need to grab it again.

Comment: @ChrisG I dont want their ID. I want the name of the item

Comment: As far as I can see, the server-side name of those enums never makes it to the client-side in the first place. However, please always add the generated HTML to your question so we can at least solve the client-side issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris comment, the value is been passed already into the function, so no need to grab it again, still if you want to grab the value by a selector, you can write the following code

```
function OtherDocument() {
     var elm= document.getElementById("availabledocument");      
     var selectedValue = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value;    
}
```

If you use jQuery then you can write the following code:

```
 $("#availabledocument option:selected").val();
```

Comment: I dont want their ID. I want the name of the item

Comment: For ex: If I select the electricbill then I want electricbill only not their id i.e. 0.

Comment: Try innerHTML instead of value, if you are using jQuery, try  text() or  html() instead of val().